# Component only fully shows when I maximize frame

Tags: java, swing, components

I'm programming the game hangman and I have a Label in the center for the word to be guessed, a score panel on the right(east) and a panel of button characters on the bottom(south). As i was moving onto painting the hangman gallows, i tried to paint a simple circle at first and add it to the left(west) of the frame, but only a small portion of the circle appeared, the problem seemed to be fixed temporarily when i maximized the frame and the resized it to its original size, how do i fix this? I created a class that extends JPanel and overrided its pain component method. what should i do so that it fully shows the circle when the program is launched.

Comment: If this were my problem and I were seeking help here, I'd take a little time to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since I'd know that this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand my problem and then help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I created a class that extends JPanel and overrided its pain component method. what should i do so that it fully shows the circle when the program is launched.

You also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of the panel so that the layout managers can use this information.

> overrided its pain component method

You should be overriding the `paintComponent()` method, not the paint() method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: 1+ it would also be nice to know what layout managers he is using for his GUI, or even *if* he's using them.